# iOS-Unity bridging - strange sentence

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am trying to join native iOS project and Unity project, exported for iOS. There seems to be a solution: 
https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity

But I am a bit confused by this sentence:

> Simply add the post build script to your Unity project (it needs to be
>   an editor script), and update the Xcode project location if needed.

What does it mean?

Comment: Why not ask it the author? https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity/issues/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script that they're talking about: [link](https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity/blob/master/demo/unity/Assets/Scripts/Editor/PostBuild.cs) needs to be added to your project as an editor script.

Unity considers any scripts that exist in folders called "Editor" as being editor scripts. So save that inside an "Editor" folder.

You want to go through that script and edit all the fields there to values that match your project. For example these two:

```
private const string XcodeProjectRoot = "../xcode";
private const string XcodeProjectName = "DemoApp";
```

This is what they're referring to with updating the Xcode project location.